# Cloud blob container uploading file working fine locally, but not working after hosting application

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I don't know why getting the problem, earlier its working fine at local environment as well as at hosting environment. But now getting issue and getting the blank `cloudBlockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri` as well as image is not uploading at container.

```cs
private async Task<string> UploadToAzureAsync(IFormFile file)
{
    try
    {
        var cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        var cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("filecontainer");

        if (await cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync())
        {
            await cloudBlobContainer.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions()
            {
                PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off
            });
        }
        var fileName = file.FileName.Split("\\").LastOrDefault().Split('/').LastOrDefault();
        var cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = file.ContentType;

        await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file.OpenReadStream());
        var url = cloudBlockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
        return url ?? string.Empty;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess is that your code is throwing an exception and is going into Exception block. Please try to rethrow the exception from there to see where exactly your code is failing. Your upload code looks ok to me.

Comment: @Sheriff - Is the answer provided was helpful for you ? if so could you please accept the answer (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in) as solution for your ask. This could be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below code:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task UploadFileAsync([FromForm] IFormFile file)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = null;
         if(CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(_configuration.GetConnectionString("StorageAccount"), out storageAccount))
            {
                var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                var container = client.GetContainerReference("fileupload");
                await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

                var blob = await container.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(file.FileName);
                await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file.OpenReadStream());

                return Ok(blob.Uri);
            }

            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
        }
```